# how to add canvas to all the widgets in a loop kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to add shadow to all the cards in a loop using python and Kivy, IDK how to add canvas in a loop, I have tried my best but I can't figure it out plz help

I tried to make a widget class and add styles there but it wasn't working, I'm new to this plz help me

Here is the code:

```
    def on_start(self):
    for _ in recent:
        self.root.ids.recent.add_widget(
            MDCard(
                MDBoxLayout(
                    MDLabel(
                        text='Name',
                        bold=True,
                        halign='center',
                    ),
                    MDBoxLayout(
                        MDLabel(
                            text='Box Type',
                            halign='center',
                            theme_text_color="Custom",
                            text_color='gray'
                        ),
                        MDLabel(
                            text='Box Type',
                            halign='center',
                            theme_text_color="Custom",
                            text_color='gray'
                        ),

                        MDLabel(
                            text='Box No.',
                            halign='center',
                            theme_text_color="Custom",
                            text_color='gray'
                        ),
                    ),
                    orientation='vertical'),
                size_hint=(1, .2),
                pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5},
                focus_behavior=True,
                md_bg_color="#eeeeee",
                unfocus_color="#eeeeee",
                focus_color="#cccccc",
                ripple_behavior=True),
            canvas=(
                Color(rgba=(0, 0, 0, 0.8)),
                BoxShadow(
                    pos=self.pos,
                    size=self.size,
                    offset=(0, -5),
                    spread_radius=(-10, -10),
                    border_radius=(10, 10, 10, 10),
                    blur_radius=20 if self.state == 'normal' else 10,
                )))
```

If you guys want to see full code:

Python:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.card.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.label.label import MDLabel
from kivy.graphics import BoxShadow, Color

recent = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


class ExcelApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'
        self.theme_cls.material_style = 'M3'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
        return Builder.load_file('Excel.kv')

    def on_start(self):
        for _ in recent:
            self.root.ids.recent.add_widget(
                MDCard(
                    MDBoxLayout(
                        MDLabel(
                            text='Name',
                            bold=True,
                            halign='center',
                        ),
                        MDBoxLayout(
                            MDLabel(
                                text='Box Type',
                                halign='center',
                                theme_text_color="Custom",
                                text_color='gray'
                            ),
                            MDLabel(
                                text='Box Type',
                                halign='center',
                                theme_text_color="Custom",
                                text_color='gray'
                            ),

                            MDLabel(
                                text='Box No.',
                                halign='center',
                                theme_text_color="Custom",
                                text_color='gray'
                            ),
                        ),
                        orientation='vertical'),
                    size_hint=(1, .2),
                    pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5},
                    focus_behavior=True,
                    md_bg_color="#eeeeee",
                    unfocus_color="#eeeeee",
                    focus_color="#cccccc",
                    ripple_behavior=True),
                canvas=(
                    Color(rgba=(0, 0, 0, 0.8)),
                    BoxShadow(
                        pos=self.pos,
                        size=self.size,
                        offset=(0, -5),
                        spread_radius=(-10, -10),
                        border_radius=(10, 10, 10, 10),
                        blur_radius=20 if self.state == 'normal' else 10,
                    )))
```

.kv file

```
MDBoxLayout:
orientation: 'vertical'

MDTopAppBar:
    title: 'Excel App'
    anchor_title: 'center'
    elevation: 2
    left_action_items: [['home', lambda x: x]]
    right_action_items:[['magnify', lambda x: x], ['menu', lambda x:x]]

MDBottomNavigation:
    panel_color: '#eeeaea'
    MDBottomNavigationItem:
        name: 'Home'
        text: 'Home'
        icon: 'home'
        MDScrollView:
            MDGridLayout:
                id: recent
                cols: 1
                spacing: 10, 10
                size_hint_y:None
                height: self.minimum_height
                row_default_height: 100

    MDBottomNavigationItem:
        name: 'Streets'
        text: 'Streets'
        icon: 'list-box'
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDScrollView:
                id: streets
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: 1, .2
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                    focus_behavior: True
                    md_bg_color: "#eeeeee"
                    unfocus_color: "#eeeeee"
                    focus_color: "#cccccc"
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 0.8
                        BoxShadow:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                            offset: 0, -5
                            spread_radius: -10, -10
                            border_radius: 10, 10, 10, 10
                            blur_radius: 20 if self.state == 'normal' else 10
                    ripple_behavior: True
                    MDBoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
                        MDIcon:
                            icon: 'arrow-right-drop-circle'
                            pos_hint: {'center_y': .5}
                        MDLabel:
                            halign: 'center'
                            text: 'Working'
                            bold: True


    MDBottomNavigationItem:
        name: 'Customers'
        text: 'Customers'
        icon: 'account'
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDScrollView:
                id: customers
```

Comment: I suggest creating a custom class that extends `MDCard` and add a rule in your `kv` that draws the desired shadow. Then use that custom class in place of `MDCard` in your code.

Comment: It worked thanks I forgot I can do it that way